# How to get the openssl hash corresponding to Fiddler root certificate

Tags: android, ssl, hash, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using [OpenSsl for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm).
I want to get the certificate hash associated with Fiddler's root certificate that I downloaded from:
http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/

So I'm executing from the command-line:

```
openssl x509 -hash -noout -in  FiddlerRoot.cer
```

But I'm getting this error instead of getting the 8 characters long alphanumeric hash:

```
unable to load certificate
15176:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:./crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:647:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

The message seems related to PEM (Privacy-Enhaced Mail), but Fiddler's cert doesn't have PEM and I don't need it since I just want the cert to "Ensure the identity of a remote computer".
Maybe I got something wrong and the hash is only for other purposes?

The command does work with other certificates that I extracted from Android at `/system/etc/security/cacerts/00673b5b.0`.  which returns `00673b5b`.
I opened both certs in notepad to compare them and notice that the cert from Android is readable format and has a PEM section, while FiddlerRoot.cer is binary and no PEM, so it may have something to do.

Notice that the certificate hash is not the same as the file's CRC32 or other file hashes, but something related to SSL (I already tested if the file's hash matched with the SSL hash but it didn't).

The reason I need the cert hash is because I think Android requires certificate files to be named with the hash and the ".0" extension: `[CertHash].0`
and installing the cert in Android in the "user" store won't work for me, it has to be in the "system" store.

Can someone provide a way/command to get `FiddlerRoot.cer` hash?
Or am I mistaken in Android's naming requirement for installing FiddlerRoot.cer in the "system" store?
Is there any other way to install FiddlerRoot.cer in the "system" store without calculating the cert hash?
Notice that from Android's user interface, installing a cert goes to the "user" store, not to "system".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PEM is not just for emails, it is the file format ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail)).

The FiddlerRoot.cer must be converted to `.pem` format before calculating the hash:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in FiddlerRoot.cer -outform PEM -out FiddlerRoot.pem
```

And then you can finally get the hash with the command:

```
openssl x509 -hash -noout -in  FiddlerRoot.pem
```